# Finding the orthogonal trajectories of $y^2=x^2(1-cx)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Here is my initial attempt:

$c=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^3}$

$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=2x-3cx^2$

$-2y\frac{dx}{dy}=2x-\frac{3x^2-3y^2}{x}$

$-2xydx=(2x^2-3x^2-3y^2)dy$

$-2xydx=(-x^2-3y^2)dy$

$2xydx=(x^2+3y^2)dy$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2+3y^2}$

Let $y=ux$; $\frac{dy}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx}$

$u+x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{2ux^2}{x^2+3u^2x^2}$

$u+x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{2ux^2}{x^2(1+3u^2)}$

$u+x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{2u}{1+3u^2}$

$x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u-3u^3}{3u^2+1}$

$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{3u^2+1}{u-3u^3}du$

$\int\frac{dx}{x}=\int\frac{3u^2+1}{u-3u^3}du$

$\ln x=\ln u-\ln (3u^2-1) +\ln K$

$\ln(3u^2x-x)=\ln (uK)$

$3y^2-x^2=yK$

The textbook says that the correct answer is $x^2+3y^2=c_1y$. Can someone find what part of the solution I messed up.

Comment: You have a sign error on the 4th line $-2xydx=(2x^2-3x^2 \color{red}{+}3y^2)dy$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find always a little sad that such issues aren't associated with a graphical representation in order to have a geometrical feeling of what really happens.

In particular here, I wondered how a family of conical curves (a family of ellipses tangent to the $x$-axis, in red) could have an orthogonal family with third degree curves (with the origin as a double point, in blue and cyan).

This is how.

[image]

Please note that the origin is an exceptional point for both families.

This figure has been realized using Matlab but the dynamical way [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sg3thbrwfo?lang=fr.) plots the curves is preferable.

Comment: I just added another way to get these curves (that you may know) using Desmos.